# VBA Excel: Too many checkboxes on worksheet, code doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, worksheet-function

I'm currently working on an MS Excel worksheet which contains 1277 checkboxes, spread over 96 rows. In this sheet, there is a column in which the total of the checked checkboxes is placed.
The idea is that when a checkbox is ticked, the total sum in this control column is added by one.

The code for this works fine, because I used the same code on different files with fewer checkboxes. 
However, when I tick a checkbox in this file with 1277 boxes, nothing happens with the control column.

Is there a limit to the total amount of objects that is allowed in a single file? Or worksheet?

And does anyone know a bypass for this one? I could split up the file in several separate ones, but I'd much rather keep everything in the same document.

Many thanks in advance!!!

Kind regards,

Marc

Answer (score 0):

There are many excel limitations but usually the numbers are really high. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx

This may help you:
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=4925
Seems the solution may be to create a new worksheet and see if it works there.

Also, are you getting any error message?

Comment: It seems indeed that the number of checkboxes can't be causing the problem. However, the code does not work. I do not get any error message. 
Thanks for the links!